# Kibana Query to get the count of occurrence

Tags: kibana

Sorry if the question is very simple as I am new to Elastic Search and Kibana.

I have below data in JSON format.

```
host.name       123
message     abcd
host.name       567
message     abcd 
host.name       123
message     mno
host.name       123
message     abcd
```

Now currently I am searching using the command  `(message:"abcd")`  and then capturing the details manually.

But what I want is to get the number of occurrence of `abcd` hostname wise .

Like

```
123  - 2
567  - 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can leverage Kibana DevTools to directly query ES Index**

Go to Kibana -> DevTools

```
GET indexName/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "message": "abcd"
        }
      }, 
      "terms": {
        "field": "host.name",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Replace "indexName" with name of the index.

**Above query will :**

a) First filter the documents with term 'abcd'

b) Aggregate/Bucket the filtered data, based on the host

Comment: It gives error on the field message  : "reason": "no [query] registered for [message]","

Comment: @user2854333: Can you please share the query you are using ?

Comment: GET applog-123-prd-2020.07-v1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "filter": {
        "message": {
          "FIELD": "scam.gen"
        }
      }, 
      "terms": {
        "field": "host.name",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: try GET applog-123-prd-2020.07-v1/_search { "size": 0, "aggs": { "NAME": { "filter": { "term": { "message": "scam.gen" } }, "terms": { "field": "host.name", "size": 10 } } } }

I also updated the query

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use a visualization for that.

Create a table visualization choose:

- Metrics : Count
- Buckets : terms => message (.keyword if needed)
- Buckets : host.name

You should have the result you need.

**Pro tips:**

1. You can export table visualization as csv:

[image]

2. You can view the generated request created by Kibana to save you time, by clicking "inspect" at the top of your visualization:

[image]

[image]